# What is the spectral energy distribution (SED)?

Tags: spectra, luminosity

I see the SED being referred to as several different things and now I am confused about what it actually is and what are its units. In particular, I find the [SED Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_energy_distribution) not understandable.

The Flux $F$ of a star/galaxy is related to its luminosity $L$ by
$$F=\dfrac{L}{4\pi d_L^2}\,,$$ where $d_L$ is the luminosity distance.
If we differentiate the quantities and remembering that the emitted wavelength $\lambda_{em}$ is related to the observed one by $\lambda_{obs}=(1+z)\lambda_{em}$, where $z$ is the redshift, we can have two quantities:

- $\dfrac{dF}{d\lambda_{obs}}\equiv f_{\lambda}$
- $\dfrac{dL}{d\lambda_{em}}\equiv l_{\lambda}$

I **think** $f_{\lambda}$ is the specta (units of [Energy][Time]$^{-1}$[Lenght]$^{-3}$) and $l_{\lambda}$ is the SED (and therefore has units of [Energy][Time]$^{-1}$[Lenght]$^{-1}$). Is this correct? Can you give me some resources (eg. papers or books) where this is written down? Thank you.

Comment: SED = Spectral Energy Distribution. It can be in flux units or in luminosity units, but is quoted as flux per unit wavelength (or sometimes flux per unit frequency).

Comment: @RobJeffries, I am sorry but I didn't understand it. Since it is "distribution", I assumed it is always per unit of wavelength (or frequency). Additionally, it has a name and $l_{\lambda}$ and $f_{\lambda}$ are two intrinsically different things, so how can we call the same to both?

Comment: Because one is just the other multiplied by $4\pi d^2$. We call a spectrum a spectrum, but that can mean a lot of different things. I guess you might distinguish between an observed SED (always flux) and an intrinsic SED.

Comment: The most important thing is: both show exactly the same frequency (or wavelength) dependence - multiplied by a constant factor (the distance to the source does not change in this regard; its distance is only important when you need the overall luminosity)

Comment: The important thing to remember is that spectral energy is radically different from the spectral photon count (because photons have different energy depending on wavelength)

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, when would we use spectral photon count?

Comment: @planetmaker, it is not true that both $f_{\lambda}$ and $f_{\lambda}$ only differ by a multiplicative constant. In fact, 
$$f_{\lambda}(\lambda_{obs})\propto l_{\lambda}(\lambda_{em})=l_{\lambda}((1+z)\lambda_{obs})$$

Comment: @RobJeffries, do you simply ignore the different scaling that goes into the function then? (The scaling I posted in my previous message)

Comment: I am not an extragalactic astronomer, so the redshift complication is unfamiliar. I would call $f_\lambda$ the observed SED. Then $l_\lambda$ would be an intrinsic SED. If you want them both to be in the same units, just divide $l_\lambda$ by $4\pi d_L^2$. However you will see all sorts of axes $\nu f_\nu$, $\lambda f_\lambda$, $f_\lambda$, $\lambda L_\lambda$ and they can all be called SEDs because they just indicate how much energy is emerging at what wavelengths (or frequencies).

Comment: @CatarinaAlves yes... I'm dealing with more local stuff where cosmic redshift is negligible :)

Comment: Thank you. I wonder if once we go to higher redshifts, people start to distinguish more the names, but I understand what @RobJeffries said about all of those quantities indicating the energy at those wavelengths (or frequencies).
Just to add that in I put the formula wrong on the comment above. It should be
$$f_{\lambda}(\lambda_{obs})\propto l_{\lambda}(\lambda_{em})=l_{\lambda}\left(\dfrac{\lambda_{obs}}{1+z}\right)$$

Comment: @CatarinaAlves the photon count matters when you are dealing with a quantum sensor, such as a CCD or the human retina.  These things detect photons, not "wave energy"